# Relation between Hermitian Matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

For a given Hermitian matrix $A$, what is the semidefinite positive matrix $B$ such that
$$\mathbf{y}^{H}B\mathbf{y} =  \left | \mathbf{y}^{H}A\mathbf{y} \right |, $$ for all $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$? The operation $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value.

**My thoughts:**

If $A$ is semidefinite positive, then $\left | \mathbf{y}^{H}A\mathbf{y} \right | =  \mathbf{y}^{H}A\mathbf{y}$ and $B = A$. But, if the matrix A is indefinite, I don't know if it is possible to construct a matrix $B$ from $A$. 
I have just tried to change the negative eigenvalues of $A$ for $-\lambda$ and construct the matrix $B$ as follows
$$A = UDU^{-1} \Rightarrow B = U\left |D\right| U^{-1},$$ where $\left |D\right|$ is the elementwise absolute value of $D$, but this certainly does not work.

Any ideas or hints to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The problem is that while the quadratic form $y^*Ay$ is perfectly smooth for any Hermitian $A$, $|y^*Ay|$ does not need to be if $A$ is indefinite.
Consider 
$$
f(t):=y(t)^TAy(t):=\pmatrix{t\\1-t}^T\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}\pmatrix{t\\1-t}=2t-1.
$$
Clearly, $|f|$ is not differentiable at $t=1/2$.

Comment: You mean $\left | y^{*}Ay \right |$, don't you?

Comment: @AlexSilva Yes. I've fixed a bit the notation.

Comment: @AlexSilva You are welcome!